# Gentoo: Can't mute when headphone plugged in

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

i can't mute when i plugged in a headphone on my laptop.
But it works in Windows 7.

Here comes output from lshw command:

> *-multimedia

```
         description: Audio device
         product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1b
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
         version: 03
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=0
         resources: irq:47 memory:fc220000-fc223fff
```

I've tried to setup customized module to kernel module:

/etc/conf.d/modules:

> module_snd_hda_intel_args="model=ich9"

But it just didn't work as expected.

Anyone could provide a nice solution here ? 
Thanks for any posts ;-P

Comment: This doesn't beling on Stack Overflow. Maybe move it to the Linux/Unix site?

Comment: This isnt really a problem related to programming.  This would be better suited on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: How does `alsamixer` show your volume settings? More likely you're muting the wrong channel.

Comment: Card: HDA Intel  and   Chip: Conexant ID 5051

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the same chip as me, but this worked for me:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=lenovo-101e 
options snd-hda-intel position_fix=1 enable=yes
```

Of course, as you might guess, I have a Lenovo laptop. This might not work for you.